# Getting error: can't find '__main__' module in 'test1' in python 3.7

Tags: python

I know this question has been asked multiple times before, but it seems each time it has something to do with the text editor, or other versions of python or anaconda etc. However, I've checked all those issues, and still can't understand why I can't get the *_main_* module to work. This is my script:

```
def test():
  print('Hello World.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  test()
```

The file is saved as *"_main_.py"* (without the quotation marks of course). This is saved in a folder I have titled test1. So this is what I get when I try and run it:

```
C:\Users\Sams PC\Desktop>python test1
C:\Users\Sams PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'test1'
```

From my understanding, the way this works is you tell python to look into the folder you've specified and have it run a script called *_main_.py*. However, as you can see, that isn't quit working and I don't understand if I'm just misunderstanding how this is suppose dto work.

Comment: go inside test folder and run python "__main__.py"

Comment: I assume you meant _ main _.py (ignore the spaces), and that works perfectly.

Comment: This article might help clear some things up for you https://realpython.com/python-main-function/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue. You need to have double underscore i.e. **__main__** I had saved my script with a single underscore i.e. *_main_*